# Memory leak while playing minecraft on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, java, ram, memory-usage, memory-leak

So I recently switched from Windows 11 to Kubuntu in order to, ironically attempt to fix a bizarre graphical glitch in a specific minecraft modpack (GT:NH) I was playing that made it unplayable.

That all went well (and that glitch did stop) but it was unfortunately replaced with another one; while playing GTNH I get memory leaks at the rate of approximately 1GB every 3-5 minutes. This is 100% consistent and has never failed to occur despite me trying and changing a decent number of things.

Most interestingly, the memory used is not associated with any processes, as the following images show. This is after having played minecraft for 15m, accumulating a bunch of leaked memory, and then closing everything, which still shows about 7-8gb of memory being used.

[sysMon 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1djh.png) [sysMon 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuMU3.png) [sysMon 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KHYJ.png) [htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoqvN.png)

Both System Monitor and Htop agree that the memory is being used up, but neither can associate the used memory with a specific process.

This has consistently caused OOM crashes (error code 9 for java mc) as well as a very characteristic OOM crash when tabbed into firefox (hard to explain, but it's when everything slows to a treacle crawl and becomes unresponsive but still functional, sound starts playing sporadically and corrupted etc) so I know this isn't just an error in the reported used memory amounts.

This issue goes away entirely on reboots, but nothing aside from a reboot seems to be able to free up the memory.

Comment: What does `free -m` show?

Comment: Exactly what you would expect. It broadly agrees with the sysMon and htop (note I had to recreate the glitched state to get this result but it's all the same.

https://imgur.com/a/5AuOEcf

Again, this is with literally all possible programs/processes closed, literally just plasma, the console, and the screenshot app running. 8gb of ram being used.